# cmake: print messages from internal .cmake

Tags: cmake, cpack

I'm trying to debug a problem I got during a `make package`:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.3/share/cmake/Modules/BundleUtilities.cmake:861 (message):
    error: fixup_bundle: not a valid bundle
```

I've seen that there are some `message(STATUS ....)` inside but they do not get printed.

as example, at the beginning the funcion `fixup_bundle` contained in that file (`/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.3/share/cmake/Modules/BundleUtilities.cmake`) there are these lines:

```
message(STATUS "fixup_bundle")
message(STATUS "  app='${app}'")
message(STATUS "  libs='${libs}'")
message(STATUS "  dirs='${dirs}'")
```

but when I run cmake I don't get those printed even with `make package VERBOSE=1`.

but if I remove the `STATUS` those get printed so I was wondering how to "actvate" the `STATUS` messages

Comment: The difference could be that `STATUS` messages go to `stdout`. Do you call `make package` e.g. inside a shell script? Or can you add some details about your host environment?

Comment: I'm calling it from shell, I have no redirection. I'm on osx 10.9

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm trying to reproduce this and it would help if you could give a minimal CMake example script including your CPack configuration. It would help to see what make rule CMake does generate for the `package` target.

Comment: oh thanks! I've updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could reproduce your problem and you won't get the status messages if CPack's source code is not changed. The behavior you're experiencing is how CPack is currently implemented.

If you look into your CMake generated `package` makefile rule you will find something like:

```
# Special rule for the target package
package: preinstall
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Run CPack packaging tool..."
    [your path here]/cpack.exe --config ./CPackConfig.cmake
.PHONY : package
```

So you're calling `cpack.exe` when doing `make package`. To reproduce your problem I just appended the following line to `CPackConfig.cmake`:

```
message(STATUS "+++ Test +++")
```

As you have already tested, only if I remove the `STATUS` keyword I see the message. So I've tested to directly call from the command line:

```
> cpack.exe --verbose --debug --config ./CPackConfig.cmake
```

But still didn't get the message. When debugging `cpack.exe` I could see that `STATUS` messages do finally call [`cmake::UpdateProgress()`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmake.cxx#L1948) and there is simply no `ProgressCallback` set in `CPack`.

I think a fix is very simple, but I'm not sure if you're willing to change CMake's source code or e.g. if you want to raise a ticket in [CMake's bug tracker](https://cmake.org/Bug/view_all_bug_page.php).

**Edit**: I've successfully tested the following code extensions for [`cpack.cxx`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/CPack/cpack.cxx) with `STATUS` messages:

```
void cpackProgress(const char *msg, float prog, void* ptr)
{
    (void)prog;
    cmCPackLog* log = static_cast<cmCPackLog*>(ptr);
    cmCPack_Log(log, cmCPackLog::LOG_OUTPUT, msg << std::endl);
}
```

and then

```
int main (int argc, char const* const* argv)
{
    [...]
    cmake cminst;
    cminst.SetProgressCallback(cpackProgress, &log);
    [...]
}
```

Comment: thanks, I've added the cpack tag to the question, maybe there's a hidden/magic flag in cpack... and a cpack guru will eventually answer. I wait before flagging as answered the question

Comment: @bibi You're welcome. Fair enough. I've added a code example for the necessary `cpack.cxx` extensions. In the currently existing CPack code only [`cmCPackGenerator::InstallProjectViaInstallCMakeProjects()`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/CPack/cmCPackGenerator.cxx#L722) is calling `SetProgressCallback()`.